# List all proper, non-trivial subgroups of $U_6$ where $U_6$ is the group of $6$th roots of unity. Also, list the generators.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, roots-of-unity

A) List all proper, non-trivial subgroups of $U_6$ where $U_6$ is the group of $6$th roots of unity:

So 6th roots of unity are $\pm1, \pm \frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{{2}}i$ How do these relate to the subgroups?

B) List the generators:

If I am not mistaken the generators of the 6th roots of unity are $\frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$. Is that correct?

Comment: Isn't that just a cyclic group with six elements?

Comment: Square and cube roots of unity are proper, non-trivial subgroups

Comment: You are missing the imaginary unit in the imaginary part

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: @GregoryGrant I believe so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_6$, so has $\varphi(6)=2$ generators: $e^{2\pi ki/6},\, k=1,5$.  These are the so-called primitive roots.

Since $U_6$ is cyclic, it has a unique subgroup of each order dividing $6$.  For instance, $\{1,-1\}$ is the one of order $2$, generated by $-1$.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Note that $\varphi:\Bbb Z_6\to U_6$ given by $[n]_6\mapsto e^{\frac{2\pi n i}{6}}$ defines an isomorphism. Generators map to generators under isomorphisms. Isomorphisms preserve subgroup structure.

---

Here $[n]_6:=\{m\in\Bbb Z: 6\mid n-m\}$.

Comment: so the generators are all values for $n=0,1,...5$?

Comment: im confused i guess by the notation

Comment: No: $n=0$ does not yield a generator, since $[0]_6+_6[0]_6:=[0+0]_6=[0]_6,$ @BlackKnightRider.